# Vue.js 3 - How can I pass data between Vue components and let both views also update?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vuex4

I tried the following.
Please note the commented line in parent.vue that doesn't even commit the new state for me.
However maybe someone can guide me to a better solution for a global state shared by multiple components?

main.js

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

const app = createApp(App);
export const store = createStore({
    state: {
        textProp: 'test',
        count: 1
    },
    mutations: {
        setState(state, newState) {
            console.log('setState');
            state = newState;
        }
    },
    getters: {
        getAll: (state) => () => {
            return state;
        }
    }

});
app.use(store);
app.mount('#app')
```

parent.vue

```js
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="seperator" v-bind:key="item" v-for="item in items">
      <child></child>
    </div>
    <button @click="toonAlert()">{{ btnText }}</button>
    <button @click="veranderChild()">Verander child</button>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import child from "./child.vue";
import {store} from '../main';

export default {
  name: "parent",
  components: {
    child,
  },
  store,
  data: function () {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          valueText: "",
          valueNumber: 0,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          valueText: "",
          valueNumber: 0,
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          valueText: "",
          valueNumber: 0,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  props: {
    btnText: String,
  },
  methods: {
    toonAlert() {
      alert(JSON.stringify(this.$store.getters.getAll()));
    },
     veranderChild() {
       console.log('child aan het veranderen (parentEvent)');
       this.$store.commit('setState', { // This is especially not working.
             textProp: 'gezet via de parent',
             count: 99
         })
       this.$store.commit({type: 'setState'}, {
         'textProp': 'gezet via de parent',
          'count': 99
          });
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.seperator {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.parent {
  /* background: lightblue; */
}
</style>
```

child.vue

```js
<template>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="inputDiv">
      text
      <input @change="update" v-model="deText" type="text" name="deText" />
    </div>
    <div class="inputDiv">
      nummer
      <input v-model="hetNummer" type="number" name="hetNummer" />
    </div>
    <button @click="toonState">Toon huidige state</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import {store} from '../main';

export default {
  name: "child",
  store,
  data: function() {
    return {
      'hetNummer': 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    update(e) {
      let newState = this.$store.state;
      newState.textProp = e.target.value;
      // this.$store.commit('setState', newState);
    },
    toonState()
    {
      console.log( this.$store.getters.getAll());
    }
  },
  computed: {
    deText: function() {
      return '';
      // return this.$store.getters.getAll().textProp;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.inputDiv {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.child {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  /* background: yellow; */
  margin: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a misconception about JavaScript unrelated to Vue/Vuex.  This doesn't do what you expect:

```
state = newState;
```

**Solution (TL;DR)**

```js
setState(state, newState) {
  Object.assign(state, newState);
}
```

Instead of setting the `state` variable, merge the new properties in.

**Explanation**

- Object variables in JavaScript are *references*.  That's why if you have multiple variables referring to the same object, and you change a property on one, they all mutate.  They're all just referring to the same object in memory, they're not clones.

The `state` variable above starts as a *reference* to Vuex's state object, which you know.  Therefore, when you change properties of it, you mutate Vuex's state properties too.  That's all good.

But when you change the whole variable-- not just a property-- to something else, it does *not* mutate the original referred object (i.e. Vuex's state).  It just breaks the reference link and creates a new one to the `newState` object.  So Vuex state doesn't change at all.  Here's a simpler [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/vmrwofkt/).

**Opinion**

Avoid this pattern and create an object property on `state` instead.  Then you can just do `state.obj = newState`.

Comment: Note: the question is  using vuejs 3 and vuex 4 and thanks for this good explanation

Answer (score 0):

You should use a spread operator `...` to mutate your state as follows :

```
 state = { ...state, ...newState };
```

[LIVE EXAMPLE](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-vuex-4-modules-in-vue-3-with-typescript-forked-jtejs?file=/src/main.ts:291-332)

but I recommend to make your store more organized in semantic way, each property in your state should have its own `setter` and `action`, the getters are the equivalent of computed properties in options API they could be based on multiple state properties.

```
export const store = createStore({
  state: {
   
    count: 1
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_COUNT(state, _count) {
      console.log("setState");
      state.count=_count
    },
   INC_COUNT(state) {
     
      state.count++
    }
  },
  getters: {
    doubleCount: (state) => () => {
      return state.count*2;
    }
  }
});
```

**Note : ** no need to import the store from `main.js` in each child because it's available using `this.$store` in options api, but if you're working with composition api you could use `useStore` as follows :

```
import {useStore} from 'vuex'
setup(){
    const store=useStore()// store instead of `$store`
}
```